# Use self.master.master. Is excessively an indication of an error in the program structure?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code uses the syntax a lot:** `self.master.master.widget` ...

Is this an error in the structuring of the program for abusing the `self.master.master` ...?,

Is it bad practice and should I replace it with another function?.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Spinbox, Listbox, StringVar
from tkinter import SINGLE, ANCHOR, END, S,N,E,W

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)          
        frame_3 = B3_class (self)
        frame_3 .pack()
        #.........
#-------------------------
class B3_class(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)  
        #_____C O N T A I N E R:
        self.frm_B3 = Frame (self, bg='#31343a', width=172, height=65)
        self.frm_C1 = Frame (self, bg='#11161d', width=60, height=65)

        self.label_filas = Label (self.frm_B3, width=18, bg='#11161d', fg='#969696', bd=2, anchor= E)
        label_title = Label (self.frm_B3, text='Seleccione  Mobil :', font=('Calibri',9,'bold'), bg='#31343a', fg='white', bd=0)
        # self.label_miniature = Label (self.frm_C1, image=self.master.Miniatures[0], bd= 0)
        # This label is a container for the images that are changing ...
        self.listbox = Listbox_class (self.label_filas, width=11, height=1)
        self.spinbox = Spinbox_class (self.frm_B3, width=13, bd=0)

        #_____Position:
        self.frm_B3 .grid (column=0, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        self.frm_C1 .grid (column=1, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)

        self.label_filas .grid (column=0, row=0, padx=(0,5), pady=(0,2), sticky=N)
        label_title .grid (column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0), sticky=W)

        self.listbox .grid ( padx=(19,0), pady=(0,5), sticky=N)
        self.spinbox .grid (column=0, row=2, padx=11, pady=(3,3), sticky=W)

        #__________Propagación:
        self.frm_B3 .grid_propagate(False)
        self.frm_C1 .grid_propagate(False)
        self.label_filas .grid_propagate(False)
        self.listbox .grid_propagate(False)

    def change_miniature(self):
        pass # This function is responsible for changing the images of self.label_miniature,
             # for reasons of verification the code was removed

#------------------------------------------
class Spinbox_class(Spinbox, B3_class):
    def __init__(self, master, **args):
        Spinbox.__init__(self, master, **args)
        self.spinbox_variable = StringVar()
        self.spinbox_values = ['Banana','Apple','Grapes','Lemon','Cherry'] ##################
        self.config (values=self.spinbox_values,
                     textvariable=self.spinbox_variable,
                     justify='center',
                     wrap=True,
                     bd=0)

        self.bind ('<Double-Button-1>', lambda *arg: self.delete(0, END))
        self.bind ('<Return>', self.bind_listbox)

        self.spinbox_variable .trace_add ('write', self.change_variable)  
        self.spinbox_variable .trace_add ('write', lambda *arg: self.spinbox_variable.set (self.spinbox_variable.get() .capitalize()))
       

    def bind_listbox(self, event):
        spinbox = self.get()
        listbox = self.master.master.listbox.get(0)
        if listbox != spinbox and listbox != '':
            self.delete(0, END)
            self.insert(0, listbox)
 
    def change_variable(self, *args):
        spinbox = self.get().capitalize()
        if spinbox == '':
            self.master.master.listbox .delete(0, END)
        else:
            list_new = []
            for i in self.spinbox_values:
                if spinbox in i:
                    list_new .append(i)
            if list_new != []:
                self.update(list_new)
            if spinbox == 'As':
                self.master.master.listbox .delete(0, 1) 
        self.master.master.change_miniature()

    def update(self, list, *args):
        self.master.master.listbox .delete(0, END)
        for i in list:
            self.master.master.listbox .insert(END, i)
        if self.master.master.listbox .get(0) == self.spinbox_variable.get():
            self.master.master.listbox .delete(0, END)

#------------------------------------------ 
class Listbox_class(Listbox, B3_class):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):  #
        Listbox.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.config (font=('Calibri',9,'bold'),
                     bg='#11161d', fg='#00ff00', 
                     highlightthickness=0, bd=0,
                     activestyle='none',
                     justify='center',
                     selectmode=SINGLE,
                     takefocus=0)

        self.bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listbox_select)

    def listbox_select(self, event):       
        selection = self.get(ANCHOR)
        if self.get(0,END) != ():
            self.master.master.master.spinbox .delete(0, END)
        self.master.master.master.spinbox.insert(0, selection)
        self.selection_clear(0,END)
        
        self.after(100, lambda: self.master.master.master.spinbox.focus_set())


root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x130+200+200')   
app = App (root)
app .pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unclear where the first `self.master` is even set, but sure, calling nested fields the same name is a bad idea unless you have some kind of linked-list data-structure (which GUI elements generally are not)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for answering friend, can you please explain to me what you mean with nested fields, sorry but I'm new to this and it's costing me a bit.

Comment: What I understand that `B3_class` is supposed to be the parent of instances of `Spinbox_class` and `Listbox_class`, so you should not inherit the two classes from `B3_class`.  Also suggest to pass instance of `Listbox_class` to `Spinbox_class` and vice versa.

Comment: @acw1668 What I understood is that `Listbox` and `Spinbox` should not inherit from `B3_class`, also that it should create an Instance of` Spinbox` in `Listbox` and vice versa. But putting as an example : `self.master.master.master.spinbox.delete (0, END)`, which is within the only method of `Listbox`, my question is if this` function` would work like this or Would you change the `syntax` for another? Can you help me a little please, even if it is only the superficial structuring, I would really appreciate it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `spinbox_class` and `listbox_class` should not derive from `B3_class`.  The spinbox and the listbox should just do whatever a spinbox and a listbox need to do, and they should not know about each other.  Except for their basic functions, all the higher-level activity should be handled in the parent object, in `B3_class`.  Have listbox and spinbox send their events to the parent, and let the parent manipulate the two objects.

Comment: In fact, I would argue that you don't need `Spinbox_class` or `Listbox_class` at all.  You are not altering their basic behavior in any way.  Just create a `Spinbox` and a `Listbox` in the `B3_class` constructor and configure them.  Then the events can all be handled in `B3_class`.  That makes WAY more sense.

Comment: What happens is that the complete code is very large and will continue to grow, so I chose to create the classes

Comment: I understood well, but I don't know how to do it, can you please help me with an example if you could transform this function that is inside `Listbox_class`:
`def listbox_select(self, event):`
Only with that function, I think this function is the one that would give me more problems, the rest I will try to change it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't claim this is perfect, but it does bring up a display.  Note how I have reorganized things.  There is now one class, derived from frame.  That frame CONTAINS a listbox and a spinbox.  Notice how this simplifies things.  There is no more mention of "master" anywhere.  The listbox and spinbox events trigger methods in the owner object, as they should.  This should give you a leg up.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Spinbox, Listbox, StringVar
from tkinter import SINGLE, ANCHOR, END, S,N,E,W


class B3_class(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)
        #_____C O N T A I N E R:
        self.frm_B3 = Frame (self, bg='#31343a', width=172, height=65)
        self.frm_C1 = Frame (self, bg='#11161d', width=60, height=65)

        self.label_filas = Label (self, width=18, bg='#11161d', fg='#969696', bd=2, anchor= E)
        label_title = Label (self, text='Seleccione  Mobil :', font=('Calibri',9,'bold'), bg='#31343a', fg='white', bd=0)
        # self.label_miniature = Label (self.frm_C1, image=self.master.Miniatures[0], bd= 0)
        # This label is a container for the images that are changing ...
#        self.create_listbox(self.label_filas, width=11, height=1)
        self.create_listbox(width=11, height=1)
        self.create_spinbox(width=13, bd=0)

        #_____Position:
        self.frm_B3 .grid (column=0, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        self.frm_C1 .grid (column=1, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)

        self.label_filas .grid (column=0, row=0, padx=(0,5), pady=(0,2), sticky=N)
        label_title .grid (column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=(0,0), sticky=W)

        self.listbox .grid ( padx=(19,0), pady=(0,5), sticky=N)
        self.spinbox .grid (column=0, row=2, padx=11, pady=(3,3), sticky=W)

        #__________Propagación:
        self.frm_B3 .grid_propagate(False)
        self.frm_C1 .grid_propagate(False)
        self.label_filas .grid_propagate(False)
        self.listbox.grid_propagate(False)

    def update(self, list, *args):
        self.listbox .delete(0, END)
        for i in list:
            self.listbox .insert(END, i)
        if self.listbox .get(0) == self.spinbox_variable.get():
            self.listbox .delete(0, END)

    def change_miniature(self):
        pass # This function is responsible for changing the images of self.label_miniature,
             # for reasons of verification the code was removed

    def change_variable(self, *args):
        spinbox = self.get().capitalize()
        if spinbox == '':
            self.listbox .delete(0, END)
        else:
            list_new = []
            for i in self.spinbox_values:
                if spinbox in i:
                    list_new .append(i)
            if list_new != []:
                self.update(list_new)
            if spinbox == 'As':
                self.listbox .delete(0, 1)
        self.change_miniature()

    def create_spinbox(self, **args):
        self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, **args)
        self.spinbox_variable = StringVar()
        self.spinbox_values = ['Banana','Apple','Grapes','Lemon','Cherry'] ##################
        self.spinbox.config (values=self.spinbox_values,
                     textvariable=self.spinbox_variable,
                     justify='center',
                     wrap=True,
                     bd=0)

        self.spinbox.bind ('<Double-Button-1>', lambda *arg: self.spinbox.delete(0, END))
        self.spinbox.bind ('<Return>', self.bind_listbox)

        self.spinbox_variable .trace_add ('write', self.change_variable)
        self.spinbox_variable .trace_add ('write', lambda *arg: self.spinbox_variable.set (self.spinbox_variable.get() .capitalize()))


    def bind_listbox(self, event):
        spinbox = self.get()
        listbox = self.listbox.get(0)
        if listbox != spinbox and listbox != '':
            self.spinbox.delete(0, END)
            self.spinbox.insert(0, listbox)

    def create_listbox(self, **kwargs):
        self.listbox = Listbox(self, **kwargs)
        self.listbox.config (font=('Calibri',9,'bold'),
                     bg='#11161d', fg='#00ff00',
                     highlightthickness=0, bd=0,
                     activestyle='none',
                     justify='center',
                     selectmode=SINGLE,
                     takefocus=0)

        self.listbox.bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listbox_select)

    def listbox_select(self, event):
        selection = self.get(ANCHOR)
        if self.get(0,END) != ():
            self.spinbox .delete(0, END)
        self.spinbox.insert(0, selection)
        self.listbox.selection_clear(0,END)

        self.after(100, lambda: self.spinbox.focus_set())


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)
        frame_3 = B3_class (self)
        frame_3 .pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x130+200+200')
app = App (root)
app .pack()
root.mainloop()
```